# Facebook js api returning less photos than showing in user gallery

Tags: facebook

i'm getting images from a selected album but ... facebook is returning only 29 photos from 46in the gallery. I test it with the Graph API with limit of 50 and there is no change. The return amount is only 29 i can't get why?!

Comment: it's aways like this :) i post a problem and after 2min find the answer. 
The problem was that some of the photos are in statuses and you need a permission the read the statuses.